# Algebraic inequality involving n positive numbers with a unity product.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, inequality, contest-math

I came across this inequality on another website but there was no solution, so I am posting it here. Let $x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n$ (with $n\ge 3$) be positive numbers such that $\prod_i x_i = 1$. Prove that $$\left(1 + \sum x_i\right)\sum \frac{1}{1+nx_i}\ge\sum x_i.$$
I tried playing around with the individual terms on the l.h.s. to no avail, e.g. the inequality is equivalent to $\sum\frac{1+nx_i}{1+nx_j}\ge n\sum x_i$ but I don't see a continuation from here. Note that the original inequality is stronger than $\sum\frac{1}{1+nx_i}\ge \frac{n}{1+n}$, which in itself is not obvious.
Any ideas?

Comment: Your second inequality is true and easy enough.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg, if $n=3$, the standard substitution $x_i=y_{i+1}/y_i$ works, what is the general case? Edit: oh, I think $x_i = (\prod_{j\ne i} y_j)^\frac{1}{n-1}/y_i$ works.

Comment: For the proof of the second inequality in the general we can use the Vasc's RCF Theorem.

Comment: I have a proof of the first inequality for $n\in\{3,4,5\}$.